# Can't rewrite url in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` I have the following code:

```
server {
    listen 80 default; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log  /usr/share/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /usr/share/nginx/error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then trigger 404
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        rewrite www.some-url.com break;    <----- added this line

        server_name_in_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

Althought I'm not sure this is correct (I tried reading the documentation for ngx_http_rewrite_module but still I don't understand it throughly...)

What I want is for **any listener on 80 on ANY url directive** to have "www.some-url.com" in his browser (my custom url). Can anyone help me on this one please?

Comment: change `server_name localhost;` to `server_name some-url.com;`

Comment: @TheBoogieMan no luck...